# How do you create an empty mutable list in Racket?

Tags: list, racket, mutable

For a regular list you have plenty of options, `(list)`, `null`, `'()` all work. But how do you construct an empty *mutable* list? [The documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html) doesn't seem to provide any nullary constructor function.

Comment: From the docs: "the empty list is also the empty mutable list"

Comment: @stchang that's what I get for only looking at the function documentation. respond as an answer and I'll mark correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to know what is the proper terminator for a mutable proper list then it's the same as for immutable. Evaluating `'()` gives the same answer as evaluating `(mlist)` so there is no difference from immutable lists.

If you are looking to mutate a list that starts with zero elements, like mutating an empty list by adding an element in front,  you cannot do this. The empty list `()` is an immutable singleton in all Scheme systems. It is the only representation of a empty list. You have two possible workarounds: Make a dummy `mcons` to represent the head of your data structure that always is before the first element or just mutate the binding for the first element. Depending on how you are going to deal with ops on empty structures they vary in usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Racket manual](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html) it is clearly specified:

> Similarly, a mutable list is not a list, except that the empty list is also the empty mutable list.

So the same operators used to build an empty list can be used to build an empty mutable list.

The reason is very simple: an empty list is a special data structure without components: so, if you don't have components, there is nothing that can be mutated. So, a mutable empty list is the *same* object that an empty list. You can mutate only the car or the cdr of a mutable pair with `set-mcar!` or `set-mcdr!`, for the simple reason that they *are* components of a data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're up list creek without immutability, why not go all in with [`milst`s](https://docs.racket-lang.org/compatibility/mlists.html?q=mlist#%28def._%28%28lib._compatibility%2Fmlist..rkt%29._mlist%29%29)? An advantage is that there are 'constructor' semantics available for empty mutable lists...and a few utility procedures for working with mutable lists too.

```
#lang racket
(require compatibility/mlist)
(define empty-mutable-list (mlist))
```

It's probably worth mentioning that `'()` is also an mlist:

```
> (mlist? '())
#t
```